# How do I convert voltage square wave signal to 4-20mA signal

Tags: 4-20ma, tachometer

At school we are looking for a sensor that is able to count/sense the rpm that the shaft is turning at. 
I have found a sensor which does this but it sends out a voltage square wave: [Datasheet](https://www.lenord.de/fileadmin/kundenbereich/produkte/gel2474/ti2474_e.pdf)

I need this converted to a 4-20mA analogue signal (higher rpm = higher current).

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in Advanced!

Comment: This device doesn't output more than 20mA. Problem solved. Not sure about your voltage requirement on the other hand.

Comment: @lancovici, yes, but doesnt that still make it a block signal? i need it to be a analogue signal (updated question too.) Thanks!

Comment: You install a PLC that counts the pulses and outputs an analog output of 4-20mA.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Would a plc be fast enough for that? and would there be any other way to do it without a plc? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you'd be using a toothed wheel to generate the pulses, whats the PRF for 4 ma and the PRF for 20 mA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really a waste of capabilities of the sensor that you linked to try to convert its quadrature square wave output to a 4-20mA current loop signal. The sensor is really designed to be able to sense both direction and RPM of the gear wheel. RPM of course related directly to the frequency of the square wave output.

To do the conversion with off the shelf hardware you want to search for "frequency to current converter 4-20mA". You will find many products that will do just what you want.

On the other hand it would make way more sense to get a sensor that directly outputs the 4-20mA signal in the first place. Search for "tachometer with 4 20ma output" to see many things to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, it made me find a shaft tachometer that did exactly 4-20mA linear to the frequentie. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a binary counter (like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/CD4060BM96/296-31513-1-ND/3505795)), a timing pulse generator to reset the counter every 'x' time period (best time period would be however long you think it'll take to reach near max. count [8,192 for the linked counter] @ max possible RPM); then feed the output to a DAC (like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/DAC8541Y%2F250/296-12427-1-ND/431945)) to provide your wanted analog signal.

Alternately, you could get a low-cost uC & program it to do the same thing with one of its internal pulse-counters & DACs (there are several which are far more than capable for this application & cose under $4.00 USD)

Comment: Most uC's internal DACs alone are not suitable for this application. The 4-20mA sensor interface requires a **current sink**.

Comment: @RainerP. As long as the DAC is capable of 20mA output, doesn't adding the appropriate value series resistor to the output pin accomplish exactly that?

Comment: Usually, the receiver supplies 24V to the transmitting sensor, which acts as a variable load that draws a current somewhere from 4 to 20mA. The drawn current is then measured at the receiving side.

Comment: @RainerP. ok, that makes sense then. ... so you'd have to run a transistor from the output signal in order to convert my output. ... Probably easier to find something else that's pre-made for that usage.

Comment: There are pre-made DACs for that purpose, like the [AD421](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD421.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In the asphalt plant world they typically use tach cards.  Look up Libra asphalt control systems.

They make these little programmable relays like the LOGO, they have came a long way since they were first created.  Last I looked at them you can get them with high speed pulse inputs and an analog 4/20mA output in their standard configurations.  These type of relays allow the user to program them with the built in push buttons and screen built into the relay.

I would recommend getting one and using it for many of your future task and designs.

Software is generally a free download if you rather program from your laptop.

39 years working as an industrial electrical engineering tech, currently a tech IV.  Also designed custom control panels in my own UL508 / 508A shop when I first got into this industry.

Good luck